# Podemos reaproveitar as traduções do site vindas do SOpt?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, localization

O [Stack Overflow em português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com) (SOpt para os íntimos) é, como acredito que todos aqui já saibam, uma comunidade de programadores bastante ativa em língua portuguesa na rede Stack Exchange e que está toda* traduzida para o português. A tradução inclui medalhas, tópicos de ajuda, FAQ, interface gráfica e tags.

Seria possível aproveitarmos as mesmas traduções do SOpt aqui no nosso novo site? Se possível de forma que alterações por lá se reflitam automaticamente por aqui e vice-versa (acho que o *transifex* dá conta disso).

<sup><sup>* Bem, na verdade toda não, quase toda.</sup></sup>

Comment: Victor podes marcar a resposta do @Gabe como certa? Isto se achares que é a certa, mas não há muitas duvidas não é.

Comment: @JorgeB. Sinceramente, a menos que você tenha uma razão muito forte para me convencer, eu me recuso a marcar a resposta do Gabe como certa, pelo simples fato de considerá-la errada, mesmo sendo a resposta oficial da SE. O meu downvote na resposta dele e minha não-aceitação ficam como forma de protesto contra o status-declined.

Comment: Victor desculpa fiquei com a ideia errada, claro que tu é que decides qual é a resposta certa se existir uma.

Comment: @Gabe há novidades quanto a este assunto?

Comment: @JorgeB. Sobre a tradução do PT SE? Não. Não acredito que sites de língua serão traduzidos.

Answer (score 8):

Talvez a pergunta ideal seja: queremos traduzir o Portuguese Language (PL)? Os motivos para um e para outro são óbvios: a utilização de um idioma automaticamente inibe, ou até impede, a participação daqueles que não dominam o outro.

Por exemplo, um falante de português pode pensar o seguinte ao encontrar o PL em inglês:

> Por que um site de perguntas e respostas sobre a língua portuguesa está em inglês? Não faz sentido!

Por outro lado, uma pessoa que estuda português como segundo idioma pode pensar, caso o site seja em português:

> Qual é o sentido de existir um site para me ajudar a aprender português, já em português? Não entendo nem os links!

Então, seria ótimo poder ter os dois, talvez com uma clássica bandeirinha (ou outro símbolo) para fazer a troca.

Sobre a utilização das *strings* traduzidas no SOpt, teoricamente sim, é possível, pois isso foi afirmado como algo que facilitaria a abertura do Super User em Português, e a maior parte das *strings* de lá também existe aqui. Veja [esse post](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2545/22235) do Tim Post:

> The actual localization component
>
> We have come very far when it comes to the process that we use to
> bring up a site in a new language. I'm going to be posting more (very
> soon) on Area 51 about where we stand with it, where we hope to be at
> the end of the year, and what this means for the growing number of
> communities that have been waiting for us to reach this point.
>
> The process still requires a dedicated community manager per site.
> We're going to (we hope) get things to the point where we only need
> one community manager per language, which means that SUPT could simply
> use the translations from SOPT, make some site-specific changes, and
> be ready to go for a beta.
>
> We're not there yet. I know it sounds like that should be easy, it
> should be easy, and that's why we're working on it.

Em português:

> O problema com sites internacionais
>
> O processo para criar sites internacionais já melhorou bastante,
> comparada ao que era antes. Nos próximos dias vou escrever, na Area
> 51, sobre o estado atual, como queremos estar até o final do ano e
> como isso afeta todas as comunidades que estão aguardando alguma
> resposta nossa.
>
> No momento, ainda é necessário que exista um gerente de comunidades
> dedicado a cada um dos sites. Nosso plano (esperamos) é eventualmente
> precisar apenas de um gerente por língua. Isso significa que o SUpt
> poderia usar as mesmas traduções de interface que o SOpt, mais algumas
> pequenas alterações, e partir para o beta.
>
> Ainda não estamos nesse estado. Sei que não parece tão complicado, e
> não devia ser tão complicado. É por isso que estamos revendo o
> processo.

Comment: Só um detalhe que venho chamar a atenção: "Qual é o sentido de existir [um site para me ajudar a aprender inglês](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), já em inglês? Não entendo nem os links!"

Comment: Concordo Victor, mas também acho importante ressaltar que no "mundo atual", o inglês tem um papel central, é uma linguagem que funciona de *hub* entre outras. Obviamente não vamos ter o PL traduzido para 20 idiomas, mas um francês que queira aprender português pode ter o caminho facilitado se encontrar uma comunidade em inglês, já que a probabilidade de ele falar inglês é bem maior do que de falar qualquer outra língua, além da sua nativa, claro.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Primeiro porque o site não é direcionado a pessoas que não sabem nada de Inglês e querem tirar uma pequena dúvida, mas sim para quem está estudando a língua. Segundo porque a alternativa a isso seria ter o ELL em *todas as línguas do mundo* (conteúdo e interface), e isso não faz sentido algum. Não há resposta correta para esses problemas, qualquer solução vai ter falhas, mas os sites sobre línguas mantidos em Inglês é a solução menos restritora

Comment: @Gabe Então, o que acha de postar uma resposta mais elaborada e mais detalhada? Com certeza você é a melhor pessoa para isso.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Minha resposta não seria muito diferente da do Molx. Ele disse tudo que eu diria. A palavra final não é minha, mas deveria haver um apoio incondicional, e baseado em dados, da comunidade, para que o PL fosse totalmente traduzido para o Português.

Answer (score 4):

Os sites de língua da rede são direcionados a um público internacional, não aos usuários que falam Português nativamente, como no caso do SOpt. É uma distinção importante.

O PL não tem nenhum tipo de tratamento especial em relação ao French, Spanish, Japanese, etc, só por ter um SO na língua. Os sites sobre línguas são considerados "neutros", que é só um eufemismo para "Em Inglês, porque os usuários podem vir de qualquer lugar, e falar qualquer língua, então usamos o Inglês como língua comum".

Definitivamente não é ideal, mas qualquer outra alternativa apresenta problemas ainda maiores - como impedir que algum estrangeiro determinado a aprender Português não consiga participar do site.

Comment: I agree that Portuguese.SE should not be an exception. All language sites should get a translated interface, [like you promised four years ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82176/localization-the-state-of-the-nation/82229#82229). But since you already have all necessary elements in place for Portuguese, this site should have an interface in Portuguese.

Comment: @Gilles Expecting every language site to have a translated interface is unrealistic. It doesn't scale at all and there are also technical issues with some of the languages (like Arabic).

Comment: @Gabe Também acho que tens razão.

Comment: Gabe, we/you have some technical issues with Arabic (I guess that this is due to Arabic being a right-to-left language with a very different alphabet), ok, so when the people from the Arabic language site ask a question like this one, you or someone else who works for SE could put a "status-declined" there. But, what is the technical issue with Portuguese? Since this already had been done with SOpt, it should be a pretty low technical barrier to maybe deserve a "status-deferred" instead a "status-declined". CC @Gilles;

Comment: E sobre a maioria dos usuários poderem vir de qualquer lugar, sim isso é verdade, mas adivinhe de onde uns 95% deles virão? E você acha que desses 95%, quantos não falam inglês? CC @Gilles

Comment: What about rus.stackexchange.com? I just came across this site a couple of weeks ago. It seems to be a site in Russian about the Russian language. (Alas, there's also russian.stackexchange.com.) It didn't pass through Area 51. How did that happen?

Comment: Also this seems relevant: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/a/13204/63809 The answer says "let's do full immersion", but then in the comments it's saying "but the UI will be in English". I think you could opt to give a translated UI to all sites, which have a StackOverflow in that language. Maybe in 10 years time, you'll have SOar and then Arabic.SE could inherit the UI (if they want). There are not that many differences in UI, right?

Comment: @VictorStafusa We can't make this decision based on "guessing". As I said, SOpt is in Portuguese because it is made **for** Brazilians and Portuguese, who speak Portuguese 100% of the time. Pt.SE is made for *anyone* with interest in learning more about the Pt language. There's more at play here than our unwillingness to flick a switch. I was replying to Gilles argument that "every language site should be translated", technical issues are not at play in Pt.SE's case.

Comment: @Earthliŋ rus.stackexchange.com was part of the Hascode.ru community, and was migrated when we merged it into our own network. The site had existed for years, and had its own community already. We couldn't just set it to English and ruin what they'd built over the years. Japanese.SE *isn't* in Japanese, Spanish.SE will not be in Spanish. That's not the policy for language sites.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that technical issues like right-to-left text in Hebrew or Arabic are not the dominant ones regarding having — or not having — a translated interface.

Comment: I have to agree with @Gabe this site is for anyone with interest in learning more about the Portuguese language. If I start this week to learn Portuguese is difficult to me understand Portuguese.

Comment: It would be interesting to have a setting for the user to chose the language of the interface. It is a pity otherwise to have all those SOes, SOpt translations and not being able to use them to boost Spanish.SE, Portugue.SE and others.